# New to Angular, why can I access {{item.id}} in .html but not in .ts?

Tags: angular

In my .html file I have:

```
let item of items
```

so that I can access

```
{{item.id}}
```

but if I type this in my .ts file, I don't get the data. Even if I leave out the brackets. If I have normalized the item for the html to show, how do I show it in the .ts?

Comment: post what you have tried in ts

Comment: Coming from Android I am used to being able to write "String data = dataSnapshot.child(user).child("id").getValue().toString();". I tried many things:
    string id;
 id = item.id;

      this.id = itemList.map(item => {
        return {
          id: item.data().id}})

Comment: Remember, that you have to use `this.` in your ts files, but not in the html template.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way in **.ts** file

```
//First define your array like this.

items : any = []; 

readData(){
    for(let i = 0 ; i < this.items.length ; i++){
        console.log("ID is ::: ",items[i].id);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'any[]'"
I don't understand why it says number when it is a string.

Comment: If you want to keep the same syntax as the HTML, you can also do something like `items.forEach((item) => { console.log(item.id); });`

Comment: @Dipack Thanks for your suggestion. If you fell my answer is correct then you can appreciate it by  upvote it also. :)

Comment: @Sachin Shah Error getting document: TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined

Comment: @Dipack First I add data to the item: "this.items = mydatasource...;" then I call your function: "this.items.forEach..." and I get "ERROR TypeError: this.items.forEach is not a function"
Isn't there a one-liner without a service or function? It is simple in Java, why so complicated in JavaScript?

Comment: @Silkit, Your data source must be of type array. If it's not an array, then the interpreter will throw the error that you are getting, complaining that `forEach` is not a function. You can read more at the MDN JS Array [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: @Silkit I have msg on skype

Comment: the OP is specifically asking about the ``forOf`` loop in Ts . this is not solving his problem

Comment: @CruelEngine This is what I used in any code. It works fine for me. So I hope it will also works for him/her also. :)

Comment: @Silkit I have update my answer. I forgot to type `length` in loop. I have update it.

Answer (score 0):

"let item of items" is used to loop through an array in TypeScript. since it is a one-liner, it makes it's usage in *ngFor in HTML easy.

TypeScript:

```
var items=[1,2,3,4,5];
for (let item of items)
{
    console.log(item);    // or console.log(item.id);
}
```

Anyways, you can always opt to use the conventional for loop syntax, which is as follows:

```
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
for(let i = 0 ; i < items.length ; i++)
{
    console.log(items[i]);     // or console.log(items[i].id);
}
```

*Edited

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers talks about `forOf` Loop in Typescript :

There is a `forOf` Loop in typescript . It is `not an angular way of Loop` but it is a `feature in typescript` and `ngFor` directive uses this .

Lets say i have a array data which is of type `{name : string , value : string}`.

```
  testData : Array<{name : string , value : string}> = [
    {name : 'Test1' , value : 'Test1'},
    {name : 'Test2' , value : 'Test2'},
    {name : 'Test3' , value : 'Test3'},
    {name : 'Test4' , value : 'Test4'},
    {name : 'Test5' , value : 'Test5'}
  ];
```

To acceess the way you want to , i would simply use forOf loop and it can be done in the below way :

```
for( let i of this.testData){
  console.log(i);
  console.log(i.name);
}
```

Now considering your variable used in the code snippet added ,

i would simply use the loop in the below way :

```
for(let item of this.items){
 console.log(item.id)
}
```

I have even created a stackblitz example which you can checkout here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5azbsq